# Sorting in an extended Fiori App

Tags: sap-fiori

This is the code below I am using:

```
getHeaderFooterOptions: function() {
    var that = this;

    var oHeaderFooterOptions = {
        sI18NMasterTitle: "MASTER_TITLE",
        buttonList: []
    };

    oHeaderFooterOptions.oFilterOptions = {
        onFilterPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.onShowFilter, that)
    };

    var sortItems = [];
    var sortText=null;
    var sortKey = null;
    var sortKey = "WiCreatedAt";
    sortItems.push({
        key: "WiCreatedAt",
        text: "Descending"
    });
    sortItems.push({
        key: "WiCreatedAt",
        text: "Ascending"
    });

    oHeaderFooterOptions.oSortOptions = {
        aSortItems: sortItems,
        sSelectedItemKey: "WiCreatedAt",
        onSortSelected: jQuery.proxy(that.handleSort, that)
    };

    return oHeaderFooterOptions;
},

handleSort: function(sSortKey) {
    //alert("msg");
    if (sSortKey === "WiCreatedAt" ) {
        oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter(sSortKey,false);
    }

    else if (sSortKey === "WiCreatedAt"  ) {
        oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter(sSortKey, true);
    }
    this.getList().getBinding("items").sort(oSorter);
},
```

Is there any way we can also pass the text the way we are passing the key in the  oHeaderFooterOptions.oSortOptions object and how do we obtain the properties like aSortItems and sSelectedItemKey, is there any API for this?

Comment: I want to sort the items in the master list in ascending and descending order based on the key, "WiCreatedAt". Can anyone please guide me how to modify my code and get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

We try to understand the issue. Please have a look at the following coding:

```
getHeaderFooterOptions: function() {
    var that = this;

    var oHeaderFooterOptions = {
        sI18NMasterTitle: "MASTER_TITLE",
        buttonList: []
    };

    oHeaderFooterOptions.oFilterOptions = {
        onFilterPressed: jQuery.proxy(that.onShowFilter, that)
    };

    var sortItems = [];
    var sortText=null;

    sortItems.push({
        key: "Descending",
        text: "WiCreatedAt sorted descending"
    });
    sortItems.push({
        key: "Ascending",
        text: "WiCreatedAt sorted ascending"
    });

    oHeaderFooterOptions.oSortOptions = {
        aSortItems: sortItems,
        sSelectedItemKey: "WiCreatedAt",
        onSortSelected: jQuery.proxy(that.handleSort, that)
    };

    return oHeaderFooterOptions;
},

handleSort: function(sSortKey) {
    //alert("msg");
    if (sSortKey === "Ascending" ) {
        oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("WiCreatedAt",false);
    }

    else if (sSortKey === "Descending"  ) {
        oSorter = new sap.ui.model.Sorter("WiCreatedAt", true);
    }
    this.getList().getBinding("items").sort(oSorter);
},
```

Please also have a look at the sample application “Manage Products” in SAP WebIDE.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. But my question is if I have to sort based ascending and descending based on one key then how will I proceed?

Comment: It looks like the code should work. If you're getting an error, you could explain the error you receive in a bit more detail?